# Не запускается MySQL-сервер на CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, centos, innodb

Здравствуйте.
Не запускается MySQL, делаю restart через service mysql restart получаю следующее:

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL. ERROR!
ERROR! Failed to restart server.
```

В логе ошибок появляется следующее:

```
160626 07:23:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.13-MariaDB) starting as process 1631 ...
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2779780504
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2779794489
2016-06-26  7:23:44 139672214771744 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 2016-06-26 07:23:45 7f07c2bfc700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139671308846848 in file log0recv.cc line 1195
96 97 98 99 InnoDB: Failing assertion: !page || (ibool)!!page_is_comp(page) == dict_table_is_comp(index->table)
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
160626  7:23:45 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=268435456
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 578601 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48400
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2b)[0x7f07f966ee0b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x475)[0x7f07f91cf055]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x3d6700f7e0)[0x7f07f87d57e0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f07f6bfc625]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f07f6bfde05]
mysys/stacktrace.c:247(my_print_stacktrace)[0x7f07f937d7cf]
log/log0recv.cc:1751(recv_recover_page_func(unsigned long, buf_block_t*))[0x7f07f9380034]
buf/buf0buf.cc:4820(buf_page_io_complete(buf_page_t*))[0x7f07f948183a]
fil/fil0fil.cc:6084(fil_aio_wait(unsigned long))[0x7f07f94dc7f8]
srv/srv0start.cc:543(io_handler_thread)[0x7f07f940db10]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x3d67007aa1)[0x7f07f87cdaa1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f07f6cb293d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160626 07:23:45 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/ovz1.valerka2.zm9y1.vps.jino.ru.pid ended
```

Перерыл весь Google, подобной проблемы не нашел. Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Comment: Это свежая инсталляция или какое-то время MySQL до этого работала? Ставили из пакета или собирали MySQL сами? Может этому событию предшествовали какие-то работы с MySQL?

Comment: Работала до того, как произвел восстановление из резервной копии сервера. Причем интересно то, что после восстановления MySQL как бы работает, можно зайти в phpMyAdmin, но если производить какие-либо действия, например удалять таблицы, то сразу отваливается. Ставил из пакета, и обновлял MySQL до последней версии.

Comment: А как восстанавливали? Разворачивали дамп? Пользовались какой-то утилитой, работающей с бинарными данными?

Comment: Стандартными средствами панели хостинга. Вполне возможно, что проблема именно из-за этого, но хотелось бы разобраться, почему такое произошло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас повреждено табличное пространство InnoDB. Дело в том, что таблицы и индексы InnoDB хранятся в едином большом файле (который может быть разбит на несколько), который в свою очередь отображается в память. Устроена InnoDB довольно сложно, так как писалась в качестве замены Oracle причем во времена, когда Linux был не особо стабилен.

Самым надежным способом восстановления является работа с дампом: честно снять SQL-дамп, честно его восстановить. Однако, это может быть довольно дорогостоящей по времени операции. Существуют утилиты, которые работают непосредственно с табличным пространством, позволяя копировать бинарные файлы. С большой долей вероятности восстановление вашего дампа осуществлялось при помощи такой утилиты. Возможно она не была обновлена вслед за версией MySQL или созданные дампы были для предыдущей версии MySQL и бинарные файлы табличного пространства не подходят для новой версии.

В любом случае следует немедленно обратиться за помощью в службу тех.поддержки хостинга, так как полная информация есть только у них.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения.